# Python social auth Django pipeline nonetype errors

Tags: python, django, pipeline, python-social-auth

I have the following pipleline in my Django settings file for Facebook login with python-social-auth module:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
)
```

My login method looks like that:

When I try to authenticate for the first time with Facebook I'm getting the following:
AttributeError at /complete/facebook/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'

```
def user_login(request):
    """ Login page view."""

    #context = RequestContext(request)
    context = RequestContext(request,
                             {'request': request,
                              'user': request.user})

    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  # authentication

    if not user.is_anonymous():
        print user
        if not request.method == 'POST':

            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('main/login.html', {}, context)

    else:
        return render_to_response('main/login.html', {}, context)
```

However, if I comment out SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE and try to login, then it's fine. Of course, once a social auth user is in a database the Pipleline is working correctly.

I would appreciate any ideas where to look for a bug.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably not your cause, because in my case I got this error whatever pipeline was, but it may help someone else.

In my case I got this error, because I deleted user from `auth_user` table, but there still existed record in `social_auth_usersocialauth` table pointing to non-existent user id which prevented from creating record with correct user.
That was solved in my case either by deleting record from `social_auth_usercoaialauth` table or fixing that record to point to existing user id.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this setting : 
SOCIAL_AUTH_ALWAYS_ASSOCIATE = True

It seems that your user is not linked to the social profile.

Comment: No, this is not the case.